# How to train separate attention weight for each label in pytorch?

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, multilabel-classification, attention-model

I am new to PyTorch. I am trying to train a multilabel LSTM-attention model where each label has its own attention weight.
I would like to ask is there a way like tf.map_fn in Keras that I can train separates attention weight using the same LSTM hidden state?

I've referred to https://github.com/iliaschalkidis/lmtc-eurlex57k. Seems like there is no similar function like tf.map_fn in PyTorch so I need to use for loop. However, I'm not quite familiar with how PyTorch saves the weight and how can I make sure that each attention weight depends on its own label.

```py
def call(self, x, mask=None):

        a = dot_product(x, self.Wa)

        def label_wise_attention(values):
            doc_repi, ai = values
            ai = K.softmax(K.transpose(ai))
            label_aware_doc_rep = K.dot(ai, doc_repi)
            if self.return_attention:
                return [label_aware_doc_rep, ai]
            else:
                return [label_aware_doc_rep, label_aware_doc_rep]

        label_aware_doc_reprs, attention_scores = K.tf.map_fn(label_wise_attention, [x, a])

        # Compute label-scores
        label_aware_doc_reprs = K.sum(label_aware_doc_reprs * self.Wo, axis=-1) + self.bo
        label_aware_doc_reprs = K.sigmoid(label_aware_doc_reprs)

        if self.return_attention:
            return [label_aware_doc_reprs, attention_scores]

        return label_aware_doc_reprs
```